# understanding the size and structure of multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

When reading an open source program, a function outputs the following multi-dimensional array. The output is referred to as `batch`. `print(batch)` generates the following output. In order to know exactly the structure of this output. I tried `print(batch.shape)`, which generates the following error message `print(batch.shape)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'`
. What are the possible ways to understand the structure/size of this type of array structure?

[image]

Comment: That's not a multidimensional array. It's a tuple of arrays.

Comment: so how to know the metadata of this tuple of arrays, such as size and structure? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tuple, like a Python list, has a `len` property

```
len(batch)   # probably gives 2
```

You can look at the properties of the elements of tuple with iteration

```
for arr in batch:
   print(arr.shape)
   print(arr.dtype)
```

Or

```
 [arr.shape for arr in batch]
```

or

```
 batch[0].shape
 batch[1].shape
```